# How can I read a file and determine its data representation as I pass it into a linked list?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, nodes, tokenize

So in this code I'm trying to take a text file, grab all of string tokens and make nodes that are added into a linked list. I'm able to grab every individual string token from this, and make a node with the 'data' field filled in correctly. The problem comes when I try and use the determinedohf function to fill in the 'type' field. I know in this code there is only one check for octal but even before then my gcc compiler is telling me there are incorrect casts to pointers/char that I'm not understanding. 
What am I missing or not doing correctly in my determinedohf function? I feel like parameters and such may also be incorrect, but I'm not sure how...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct node {

    char *data;
    char *type;
    struct node *next;

} node;


void readfile(char* filename) {

    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");

    if(file == NULL) {
        exit(1);
    }

    char buffer[51];

    while(fscanf(file, "%s", buffer) != EOF) {

        add(buffer);
    }

    fclose(file);
}

void add(char* line) {

    node *temp = malloc(sizeof(node));
    temp->data = strdup(line);
    temp->type = determine(line);
    temp->next = NULL;
    current = start;

    if(start == NULL) {
        start = temp;
    } else {
        while(current->next != NULL) {
            current = current->next;
        }
        current->next = temp;
    }
}

char* determineDOHF(node* line){

      /*supposed to determine whether the string is represented as
      decimal, octal, hex, or floating point*/
    char *dohfType;
    char input[51] = line;
    if(input[0] == '0'){
        dohfType = 'Octal';
    }

    return dohfType;

}
```

Comment: Where are your `#include`s? And what's the error message?

Comment: `dohfType = 'Octal';` isn't going to do anything useful. Even if it were `dohfType = "Octal";` you won't compare that to other string pointers unless the compiler is configured to merge duplicate string literals, and even then it would be clumsy. You would do better to use an `enum` to identify the type of input.

Comment: the includes are:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

Comment: Please edit the question instead of drip-feeding information. Better, post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which shows what you have tried.

Comment: Use enums to identify the types you want something like `typedef enum {OCTAL, STRING, HEX, DECIMAL, BOOL, etc} token_type`. Also note that hexadecimal can start with `0`, so you have to improve your check for octal

Comment: `char input[51] = line;` is not valid. To copy a string in C, you need to use `strcpy`. OTOH, there's no reason to make a copy, you can use the `line` parameter as if it was an array, e.g. `if(line[0] == '0')`

Comment: Curious, what text or who suggested using `while(fscanf(file, "%s", buffer) != EOF)`?

Comment: in your add function, it would be a good idea to always free memory after doing a malloc. Malloc is going to allocate memory to your program, which is only going to be freed if you manually do it, or close the program.

Also, in `determinedohf` you are returning a pointer to a variable local to a function. That memory region may be freed once the function returns, and you'd be reading garbage values.

Comment: regarding this line: `while(fscanf(file, "%s", buffer) != EOF) {`  What the code really wants to know is if a string was successfully input.  Any other possible considerations like was EOF encountered is useless information in the current scenario.   When using the '%s' format specifier, ALWAYS include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is one less than the length of the input buffer.  Strongly suggest: `#define MAX_CHAR (50)`  then: `char buffer[MAX_CHAR +1];  then while(fscanf(file, "%" MAX_CHAR "s", buffer) == 1) {`

Comment: it is a poor programming practice to define a struct and a typedef at the same time.  Suggest first define the struct, (with a 'tag name') then use 'typedef' to give the struct definition a short name.

Comment: the memory allocation functions (malloc, calloc, realloc) can fail.  Always check (!=NULL) the returned value (before using that returned value) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: a hexidecimal number is started with `0x` or `0X` so the posted code can be setting a 'type' to 'octal' when it is actually 'hexidecimal'

Comment: regarding this line: `dohfType = 'Octal';`   1) this will raise a compiler warning and will not work.  2) doing `dohfType = "Octal";` will result in a pointer to the string "Octal" which may be what you want, but would not be portable outside the current program execution.

Comment: the posted code references function: `determine()` and implements function: `determineDOHF()`   Which is it to be?

Comment: the variables `start` and `current` are not defined anywhere in the posted code

Comment: the function: `determineDOHF()`, if the type is not determined to be 'octal' will return a uninitialized value.

Comment: the returned value from `strdup()` needs to be checked (!=NULL) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: this line: `char input[51] = line;` will not work as expected.  it is assigning the pointer to line to a char array.  What is really wanted is: `char input[51];  strcpy( input, line );   However, the variable 'input[]` is a complete waste as the code can reference the individual characters in the `line` via statements like: `if( '0' == line[0] )`  NOTE: always place the literal on the left when making a comparison so a key stroke error, like typing `=` rather that `==` will be caught by the compiler rather than you spending hours and hours of debug time trying to find the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3 things:

1. In your add function, it would be a good idea to always free memory after doing a malloc. Malloc is going to allocate memory to your program, which is only going to be freed if you manually do it, or close the program.
2. Also, in `determinedohf` you are returning a pointer to a variable local to that function. That memory location may not be valid once the function returns, and you'd be reading garbage values. 
   If you want to use that returned string, you'd want to use malloc to allocate the `input` string. I'd strongly advise that you replace the type with an integer instead and use an enumeration to improve readability.

   enum types {
                OCTAL=0,
                DECIMAL,
                HEX
              }
3. You are assigning a type of `node *` to a type of `char` which is an invalid assignment. I suspect you want to use the type element of `node *`. So you should be doing something like this:

   strcpy(input, link->type)

In C, you can't just assign strings after initialization of a variable. You need to use strcpy to do so.

Comment: the `determineDOHF()` function is NOT returning a pointer to a local variable, it is returning the contents of that variable.  So that is not a problem (although the contents are not always initialized and that is a problem)

Comment: `char *dohfType;` `...` `return dohfType;`. This is returning a pointer, not the contents

Comment: it is returning the contents of the variable (which happens to be a pointer)  What the code should not do is return the address of the local variable.  returning the contents of a local variable is completely ok.